# Python development with arcpy package intellisense

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcpy

I have an issue using VS Code with the default python installation that comes with ArcGIS Desktop 10.6. I've set up my interpreter to point to the 64 bit version (C:/Python27/ArcGISx6410.6/..).  I'd like to use intellisense for code completion and method reference but when I start to type (arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_management) it takes VS Code forever to load the library and the method reference.

I should note that I also have ArcGIS Pro installed, and VS Code has no problem with intellisense for that installation. Maybe it has to do with VS Code being a 64 bit application and ArcGIS Desktop a 32 bit application with 64 bit geoprocessing? Anyone else have this issues specifically with the Python 2.7 arcpy package?

Comment: You can try the new language server by adding the setting `"python.jediEnabled": false` to see if that works faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried that and it didn't make a difference.  I can partially type out what I want and press Ctrl + Space and it still takes about 15 seconds to load.  Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately without access to the file that takes forever to load to see what is causing the slowness it's nearly impossible to diagnose.